# How to I get crosstool-ng C++ compiler working

Tags: c++, linux, arm, cross-platform, crosstool-ng

I'm trying to get crosstool-ng working with both C and C++. Even though I've selected C++ while using menuconfig, it doesn't seem to get built. The gcc compiler works as expected but not g++

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so any help would be appreciated.

I followed the steps found here:
[Building embedded ARM systems with Crosstool-NG](http://briolidz.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/building-embedded-arm-systems-with-crosstool-ng/)

```
$ arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-cpp main.cpp -o test
arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-cpp: main.cpp: C++ compiler not installed on this system
```

NOTE: there is no `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++` found on in the bin directory.
I've tried cross-tool version 1.16.0 and 1.15.3

```
arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-cpp -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: /opt/crossArm/.build/src/gcc-4.3.2/configure --build=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/opt/crossArm/.build/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/buildtools --with-local-prefix=/home/jgarvin/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot --disable-libmudflap --with-sysroot=/home/jgarvin/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot --enable-shared --with-pkgversion='crosstool-NG 1.16.0' --with-float=soft --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-gmp=/opt/crossArm/.build/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/buildtools --with-mpfr=/opt/crossArm/.build/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/buildtools --enable-target-optspace --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-nls --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.3.2 (crosstool-NG 1.16.0)
```

#### Code

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

In my `build.log` file I see C++ option turned on

```
[DEBUG]    CT_CC_SUPPORT_CXX=y
```

I also see it in the `config.log`:

```
configure:3030: $? = 0
configure:3019: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
```

Comment: `--enable-languages=c` is the point here, try getting that to c,c++ and it will (try to) build the c++ compiler.

Comment: yes, I saw that ".. try getting that to c,c++.." how is my question. I have C++ selected in the menuconfig.

Comment: I have no idea how crosstool-ng works, but you could start tracking back the scripts from the point on that calls this configure line. Or you could try grepping through it for "--enable-languages"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From, http://briolidz.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/building-embedded-arm-systems-with-crosstool-ng/

> Reﬁne your conﬁguration by running the menuconﬁg interface:
>
> $ ./ct-ng menuconfig

In this step, navigate to the **C Compiler** menu.  Then you can select *C++* or de-select *Java*, *Fortran*, etc.  Since **crosstool-ng** is just a bunch of scripts and patch files, it is very rare that a development build breaks things.  You can always pull from the *hg* repository.

> hg clone http://crosstool-ng.org/hg/crosstool-ng
>
> cd crosstool-ng
>
> ./bootstrap
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

This will have the latest fixes.  I have built arm cross compilers with C++ support many times using this method [including *Canadian crosses* for Mingw and i386 from an x86_64 host].

**EDIT:** I see that the *wordpress* link recommends a local install of *ct-ng*.  The commands above do a full install, putting things in */usr/local*.  Also, it seems the OP did try to set menuconfig's C++ option.  Try altering the *sjlj* value, use the latest version of *ct-ng* and install it. This produces an ARM Linux C++ cross-compiler on Ubuntu for me.  The *build.log* output can be helpful in determining if *ct-ng* decided some configuration was impossible.

Finally,  the mailing list *crossgcc@sourceware.org* doesn't require subscription afaik.  The archives at http://sourceware.org/ml/crossgcc/ can be helpful.  If you still have issues, I am sure someone on the mailing list will be able to help you.

<strike>**EDIT:** With the latest *ct-ng* installed try,</strike>

> $ ct-ng arm-cortex_a15-linux-gnueabi #Alternate *arm-yem-linux-gnueabi*
> $ ct-ng menuconfig # Tweak for your processor, gcc version, etc.
> $ ct-ng build # Go have a coffee (or work on something else).

Sorry, your host compiler was made with Linaro.  I was reading too much into your edit.

Answer (score 4):

I was having similar issue. It turns out that I was looking at the wrong bin directory under `.build`. The final version of the toolchain was installed under `~/x-tools` instead...

Comment: I experienced this too... Frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an answer on compiling c++ on arm platform:

Install crosstool-ng:

```
tar xjf <ct-ng archive>
cd crosstool-ng-<numversion>
# reset of LD_LIBRARY_PATH is required to avoid issues with crosstool-ng
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
./configure prefix=<installDir>
#example ./configure prefix=/opt/cross-rpi
make
make install
#required to make sure you get the right on in case
export PATH=<installDir>/bin:$PATH
#check what version is on now.
which ct-ng
```

Now create and launch the configuration:

```
mkdir chain-build #the directory hosting the build files of your cross compil chain
cd chain-build
ct-ng menuconfig
```

Set options are relevant to the arm platform amongst other:

**Paths and misc Options**

- Configure the maximum log level to see to **WARN** instead of **INFO** which totally clutters the logs and in my opinion makes them hard to use, way too much noise for the usual use case.

**Target options Operating System**

- Target Architecture

  - arm
- System

  - linux

**Binary utilities**
- Select the last version of binutils

**C compiler**

- GCC : Select **Show linaro Versions** then select the lastest linaro gcc (more stable than non linaro, from experience)
- C++ : Check it
  [image: c++ check]

Now build your toolchain

```
ct-ng build
# once done check the content of the bin dir
ls <yourChainInstallDir>/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin
```

You should get something like this:
[image: binaries]

of all to compile c++ code you should only need g++. To check if g++ (for arm) works ok type

```
arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++ -v
```

You should get something similar to this:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/cross1.19/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/libexec/gcc/arm-        unknown-linux-gnueabi/4.8.2/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
[...]
blahblah
[...]
gcc version 4.8.2 20130603 (prerelease) (crosstool-NG 1.19.0)
```

Once you get this message you should be ok.

The only other thing to watch out for is if you got all of the **libraries** needed to compile your code.

e.g. for instance on Raspberry-pi (using Raspbian), some of the libs have to be manually imported from **/lib** and **/usr/lib** (put then in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH).

Sometimes the includes for gcc or g++ are not copied in the include directory of the toolchain (when using crosstool-ng, got the issue a couple of times), so you need to get the includes from your /usr/include directory.