# Cross compiling JamVM for ARM linux using UBUNTU and arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc - zlib missing

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, jamvm

I'm trying to build JamVM for [FriendlyARM mini 2440](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini2440)!(http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini2440)

I installed ARM GCC using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

Next I did:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabi
make
```

An I receive these error:

```
  configure: WARNING: If you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
        If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used.
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-strip... arm-linux-gnueabi-strip
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc... arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ld used by arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc... /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking how to run the C preprocessor... arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-g++... arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of arm-linux-gnueabi-g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -E
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-g77... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-xlf... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-f77... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-frt... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-pgf77... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-cf77... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-fort77... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-fl32... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-af77... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-xlf90... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-f90... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-pgf90... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-pghpf... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-epcf90... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gfortran... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-g95... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-xlf95... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-f95... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-fort... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-ifort... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-ifc... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-efc... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-pgf95... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-lf95... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-ftn... no
checking for g77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for f77... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for cf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for f90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for pghpf... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for gfortran... no
checking for g95... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for ifort... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for ftn... no
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
checking whether  accepts -g... no
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking command to parse /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-nm -B output from arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-ar... arm-linux-gnueabi-ar
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-ranlib... arm-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-strip... (cached) arm-linux-gnueabi-strip
checking if arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc linker (/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
checking for ld used by arm-linux-gnueabi-g++... /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ linker (/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ static flag -static works... yes
checking if arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ linker (/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
(cached) (cached) checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc... (cached) arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking dependency style of arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc... gcc3
checking for ecj... ecj
checking for pthread_self in -lthr... no
checking for pthread_self in -lpthread... yes
checking for fmod in -lm... yes
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for inflate in -lz... no
configure: error: zlib is missing
```

**UPDATE:**

If I use these commands:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
./configure --host=arm-linux
make
```

I get this error after `make`:

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ehsun7b/Downloads/jamvm-1.5.4/src'
make  all-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ehsun7b/Downloads/jamvm-1.5.4/src'
Making all in os
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ehsun7b/Downloads/jamvm-1.5.4/src/os'
Making all in linux
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/ehsun7b/Downloads/jamvm-1.5.4/src/os/linux'
Making all in arm
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/ehsun7b/Downloads/jamvm-1.5.4/src/os/linux/arm'
/bin/bash ../../../../libtool   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../src  -I../../../../src  -I../../../../src -g -O2 -MT callNative.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/callNative.Tpo -c -o callNative.lo callNative.S
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../src -I../../../../src -I../../../../src -g -O2 -MT callNative.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/callNative.Tpo -c callNative.S  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/callNative.o
callNativeOABI.S: Assembler messages:
callNativeOABI.S:28: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
callNativeOABI.S:29: Error: no such instruction: `stmfd sp!,{r4,r5,ip,lr}'
callNativeOABI.S:30: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
callNativeOABI.S:31: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
callNativeOABI.S:32: Error: no such instruction: `ldr ip,[r4]@get ostack pntr'
callNativeOABI.S:33: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r2,[r4,'
callNativeOABI.S:34: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
callNativeOABI.S:35: Error: no such instruction: `ldreq r1,[ip],'
callNativeOABI.S:36: Error: no such instruction: `addne r2,r2,'
callNativeOABI.S:37: Error: too many memory references for `sub'
callNativeOABI.S:38: Error: no such instruction: `ble do_call@yes,skip stack push'
callNativeOABI.S:39: Error: too many memory references for `add'
callNativeOABI.S:41: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:42: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:43: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:45: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r3,[lr,r2,lsl'
callNativeOABI.S:46: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[sp'
callNativeOABI.S:47: Error: too many memory references for `sub'
callNativeOABI.S:48: Error: no such instruction: `bne loop'
callNativeOABI.S:51: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:52: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:53: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:55: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r2,[ip]'
callNativeOABI.S:56: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r3,[ip,'
callNativeOABI.S:58: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
callNativeOABI.S:59: Error: no such instruction: `ldr pc,[r4,'
callNativeOABI.S:61: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:62: Error: no such instruction: `ldr r2,[r4]'
callNativeOABI.S:64: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:65: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:66: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:68: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:69: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:70: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:75: Error: expecting operand after ','; got nothing
callNativeOABI.S:77: Error: no such instruction: `strge r0,[r2],'
callNativeOABI.S:78: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
callNativeOABI.S:80: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:81: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:83: Error: no such instruction: `addle pc,pc,r5,lsl'
callNativeOABI.S:85: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:86: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:88: Error: no such instruction: `ldmdb r4,{r4,r5,sp,pc}'
callNativeOABI.S:90: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:91: Error: no such instruction: `ldmdb r4,{r4,r5,sp,pc}'
callNativeOABI.S:95: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:96: Error: no such instruction: `stfd f0,[r0],'
callNativeOABI.S:97: Error: no such instruction: `ldmdb r4,{r4,r5,sp,pc}'
callNativeOABI.S:99: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:100: Error: no such instruction: `stfs f0,[r0],'
callNativeOABI.S:101: Error: no such instruction: `ldmdb r4,{r4,r5,sp,pc}'
callNativeOABI.S:104: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
callNativeOABI.S:105: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r0]'
callNativeOABI.S:106: Error: no such instruction: `ldmdb r4,{r4,r5,sp,pc}'
make[5]: *** [callNative.lo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsun7b/Downloads/jamvm-1.5.4/src/os/linux/arm'
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsun7b/Downloads/jamvm-1.5.4/src/os/linux'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsun7b/Downloads/jamvm-1.5.4/src/os'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsun7b/Downloads/jamvm-1.5.4/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ehsun7b/Downloads/jamvm-1.5.4/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: How do you specify that you are building for ARMv4t? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12964630/1163019

Answer (score 1):

By the power of necroposting, I got JamVM to arise and run on ARM Linux.

My prerequisites:

- JamVM 2.0
- GNU Classpath 0.99
- buildroot-compiled binaries for the target system (particularly, with `libz.so` and respective `include`s);

GNU Classpath:

```
ANTLR_URL=http://www.antlr2.org/download/antlr-2.7.5.jar
ANTLR_JAR=antlr-2.7.5.jar
wget -c ${ANTLR_URL} --directory-prefix=/tmp

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/arm-2008q3/bin
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
export ARCH=arm
export CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc
export LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld
export PREFIX=/usr/classpath

./configure --host=arm-linux --without-x --disable-gtk-peer \
  --disable-gconf-peer --with-antlr-jar=/tmp/${ANTLR_JAR} \
  --prefix=${PREFIX}

make -j 4

sudo mkdir -p ${PREFIX}
sudo chown -R ${USER} ${PREFIX}

make install
```

JamVM:

```
sudo apt-get install libtool zip

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/arm-2008q3/bin
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
export ARCH=arm
export CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc
export LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld

export TARGET_INCLUDE=/buildroot/output/host/usr/include
export TARGET_LIB=/buildroot/output/target/usr/lib
export CPPFLAGS=-I${TARGET_INCLUDE}
export LDFLAGS=-L${TARGET_LIB}

export PREFIX=/usr/jamvm
export CP_PREFIX=/usr/classpath

export CONFIGURE_ARGS="--host=arm-linux \
  --with-classpath-install-dir=${CP_PREFIX} --prefix=${PREFIX}" 

./autogen.sh ${CONFIGURE_ARGS}

make

# Install JamVM to the same paths both on host and target, 
# because I didn't find a configure arguments to distinguish such,
# and JamVM requires an installed GNU Classpath in order to build.

sudo mkdir -p ${PREFIX}
sudo chown -R ${USER} ${PREFIX}

make install
```

About your problems: first error is missing `libz.so` for the target platform on `-L` path, second is a wrong platform selection (probably right compiler, but wrong C sources picked).