# cross compile for armv5, but it creates v7 binary

Tags: ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling

I managed to creata an object file for arm926ej-s 
I am using debian arm on qemu

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.4 -static -O -c -mcpu=arm926ej-s  hello.c -o hello
root@at0012-ubuntu:/qemu-deb-squeeze/mnt/package# readelf -A hello
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "ARM926EJ-S"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v5TEJ
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-1
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3-D16
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
  Tag_ABI_optimization_goals: Prefer Speed
  Tag_DIV_use: Not allowed
```

but in ubuntu when I compile with our the -c it creates the executable for armv7 instead of this
So how to compile for the right cpu??
I tried $ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.4 -static -mcpu=arm926ej-s  hello.c -o hello
it creates
Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
Tag_CPU_arch: v7

Comment: How were the libraries being linked in compiled?

Comment: you need to find the right toolchain, that's the easiest.

Comment: This is effectively a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963209/why-does-arm-linux-gnueabi-g-4-4-always-build-a-7-a-binary, answered by @auselen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does arm-linux-gnueabi-g++-4.4 always build a "7-A" binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963209/why-does-arm-linux-gnueabi-g-4-4-always-build-a-7-a-binary)

Answer (score 3):

GCC's *ld* tries its best to find the correct library to link against. As far as I know, it considers *-mcpu*, *-mthumb*, *-mfpu*, and *-mfloat-abi* (see examples below). This list may not be complete, *-mthumb-interwork* is probably considered as well. If *-mcpu* is specified, the architecture is derived from that value.

So these options should be passed down to *ld*, and you ought to checked that *ld* really picks the correct multilib.

For each of these options there are built-in default values which may not lead in the right direction.

If *ld* cannot find a matching library, it falls back to the default one. There is no error message.

So in your case - assuming that you have passed *-mcpu* to *ld* and your toolchain installation is correct - there is possibly no matching multilib, and *ld* uses the default one. The linking process technically succeeds, but you do not get what you want.

---

Some examples (arm-none-eabi-gcc 4.6.2)

Available multilibs:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -print-multi-lib
.;
thumb/arm7tdmi-s;@mthumb@mcpu=arm7tdmi-s
thumb/cortex-m0;@mthumb@mcpu=cortex-m0
thumb/cortex-m3;@mthumb@mcpu=cortex-m3
thumb/cortex-m4;@mthumb@mcpu=cortex-m4
thumb/cortex-m4/float-abi-hard/fpuv4-sp-d16;@mthumb@mcpu=cortex-m4@mfloat-abi=hard@mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
```

The default

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -print-multi-directory
.
```

If a multilib for a given cpu is not found, it uses the default as well - there is no error message:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -print-multi-directory -mcpu=arm926ej-s 
.
```

There is no error message, even if the *-mcpu* is "obviously" wrong (that is the cpu is not in the list of known ARM CPUs which you can see with *arm-none-eabi-gcc --target-help*):

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -print-multi-directory -mcpu=xxx
.
```

Even with *-mcpu=cortex-m4*, the invalid multilib is chosen. cm4 only supports thumb, so this value could be derived from *-mcpu*, but the built-in default wins:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -print-multi-directory -mcpu=cortex-m4
.
```

To get the correct multlib for cm4, *-mthumb* is necessary as well, this is necessary to override the default value for the instruction set:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -print-multi-directory -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb
thumb/cortex-m4
```

To get the correct multilib for cm4 with HW support for floating point operations, *-mfpu* may not be enough:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -print-multi-directory -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard
.
```

It requires

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -print-multi-directory -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
thumb/cortex-m4/float-abi-hard/fpuv4-sp-d16
```

Further [details regarding multilib can be found here](http://www.tablix.org/~avian/blog/archives/2013/04/multilib_weirdness/) and in [auselen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963209/why-does-arm-linux-gnueabi-g-4-4-always-build-a-7-a-binary)

---

As auselen already commented, the easiest way to resolve this is to find the right toolchain, as building an ARM toolchain is another story.

Comment: This is incorrect. Each mcpu flag very specifically describes which architecture version is supported by that cpu. This is why when compiling with -c, the object ends up being for the correct architecture version. This is also the case for the assembler. No toolchain defaults can change this. I was not aware that GNU LD could be configured to automatically support several versions of the C library simply by specifying -march - can you please provide some reference for how to achieve this?

Comment: @unixsmurf: You're right. Sorry guys, mea culpa. I'm going to update my answer, just give me some time to sort things out.

Comment: @unixsmurf: I've rewritten my answer. As for your question regarding -march: It seems that -march is ignored while gcc/ld is searching for a multilib.

Comment: shame, I would have been quite happy if it did support it :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, this costs me two days!!! Just download gcc compiler for ARMv5, the compiler can be download from this: https://toolchains.bootlin.com/releases_armv5-eabi.html