# Compiling gcc with AVR options

Tags: gcc, assembly, avr

I want to generate the assembly file of my code oriented to the AVR architecture, I am using gcc version 4.7.2 with the following arguments:

g++ -O3 -Wall -S -Wp,-mmcu=atmega8 -o "src\Compression.o" "..\src\Compression.cpp"

but I am getting the following error:

cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mmcu=atmega8'

But I got the command options from the gcc website:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/AVR-Options.html#AVR-Options

There should be something that I am missing, could you help me with this please!

Comment: If you've built an AVR cross-compiler, why pass `-mmcu` through the `-Wp` option?

Comment: I didnt build an AVR cross-compiler, I used the original gcc.

Comment: In the gcc website they stated that I can use the -mmcu as a command line option, but it requires the use of -Wp so as to pass this option to the preprocessor.

Comment: gcc is a single target compiler, when gcc itself is built you have to tell it which target, what processor family, it will compile for.  if you want a host (x86 lets assume), an arm cross compiler and an avr cross compiler for example you need three separate installations of gcc, one for each target.  gcc isnt llvm/clang you cant have one compiler generate code for multiple targets.  If it doesnt recognize the command line option then the gcc you are using is likely for a different target

Comment: Hey dwelch, thanks for your comment, if you dont mind have a look at my comment on Beryllium answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `gcc` does not accept `-mmcu`, you are probably not using a gcc with support for the AVR architecture.

It's normally used like this:

> avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega328p

because it's not only the preprocessor, it's actually other tools as well which require this setting (linker, assembler).

Normally the architecture `gcc` is compiled for is indicated by a prefix, in this case it's `avr-` by convention.

So the solution is to get a toolchain with AVR support. You can download it from Atmel's web site, even for Linux.

*Update*

If you like to check the configuration of your `gcc`, you can use `-dumpmachine` to check for the target processor

> $ gcc -dumpmachine
>   i486-linux-gnu
>
> $ arm-none-eabi-gcc -dumpmachine
>   arm-none-eabi
>
> $ avr-gcc -dumpmachine
>   avr

If you look at the target specific options using `--target-help`

> $ gcc --target-help | grep march
>     -march=                     Generate code for given CPU

you can see that the Linux `gcc` does accept `-march` as well. It probably fails later.

`gcc` is a very complex piece of software, because it just supports so many different architectures. From that perspective it works *amazingly* well.

Another interesting option is `-v`

> $ gcc -v
>   Using built-in specs.
>   Target: i486-linux-gnu
>   Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.4.5-8'
>   [...]

to see how that `gcc` has been built.

And there could be another trap down the road (multi-libs), as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16688192/2390083)

Comment: Thanks for answer. What surprised me actually was that gcc would accept the line arguments for arm architecture (-march=..), but it didnt accept the line arguments for the avr architecture, knowing that the gcc website says it proviedes both of them. Anyway thanks for your answer, although I still dont understand why compiling for arm works but for avr it doesnt. I guess I can use avr-gcc.

Comment: I've updated my answer. While it could be possible that it compiles, does the ARM executable really run?

Comment: Thanks for your update, I switched now to use some toolchain with support for avr.